# Variable of date in a SQL query

Tags: vba

Can you please help with implementation variable into SQL query in VBA? I am getting syntax error of date, timestamp or ODBC, DB2  ......thank you

```
Dim startdate As Date
Dim enddate As Date
startdate = InputBox(startdate, "YYYY-MM-DD")
enddate = InputBox(enddate, "YYYY-MM-DD")
```

I am trying to implement variable into where clause in the SQL statement:

```
where atindt>='" & startdate & "' and atindt<='" & enddate & "'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to include `startdate` or `enddate` as *arguments* to `InputBox`

replace

```
startdate = InputBox(startdate, "YYYY-MM-DD")
enddate = InputBox(enddate, "YYYY-MM-DD")
```

by

```
startdate = InputBox("YYYY-MM-DD") 'perhaps with a more informative prompt
enddate = InputBox("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

and that part of the code will work as intended.